# GridView textbox value insert in another textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that contain Two TextBox and i want to insert value of TextBox1 into TextBox2 using only JavaScript.
I am using ASP.Net C#

Here is my ASPX Code :

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cal(t1, t2) {
        document.getElementById(t2).value = document.getElementById(t1).value;
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeypress="cal('MainContent_TextBox1','MainContent_TextBox2')"
                onkeyup="cal('MainContent_TextBox1','MainContent_TextBox2')" onselect="cal('MainContent_TextBox1','MainContent_TextBox2')"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

I am using that code but this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox textBox1 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox1");
            TextBox textBox2 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox2");
            textBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "cal('" + textBox1.ClientID + "','" + textBox2.ClientID + "')");
            textBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "cal('" + textBox1.ClientID + "','" + textBox2.ClientID + "')");

        }
    }
```

add RowDataBound Event To GridView

```
OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
```

and use this Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function cal(t1, t2) {
            document.getElementById(t2).value = document.getElementById(t1).value;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Is that possible on JavaScript only? Why we use GridView1_RowDataBound.

Comment: yes this is only in javascript.RowDataBound Just add event to the controls at runtime.

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: I have already posted this answer. What is unique in your answer ??

Answer (score 1):

In the [**OnRowDataBound**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event of your GridView, you can do something like this -

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox textBox1 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox1");
        TextBox textBox2 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox2");
        textBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "cal('" + textBox1.ClientID + "','" + textBox2.ClientID + "')");
        textBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "cal('" + textBox1.ClientID + "','" + textBox2.ClientID + "')");
    }
}
```

and remove the attribute from textbox in itemtemplate of gridview.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header1">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: how can i don this on JavaScript?

Comment: @user3834541: Using above code, your cal function will call for all textbox in gridview. See my modified answer... Modify your code as per the answer

Comment: It gives an Error "The name 'onkeyup' does not exist in the current context" in "textBox1.Attributes.Add(onkeyup, "cal('" + textBox1.ClientID + "','" + textBox2.ClientID + "')");" line.

Comment: @user3834541: Please add attribute in double quote("") like this - `textBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "cal('" + textBox1.ClientID + "','" + textBox2.ClientID + "')");`